# VS Code Terminal cannot run mvn command

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Windows machine and have installed VS Code 1.78.2 and i have following extensions installed in VS Code.
1.Extension Pack for Java (v0.25.11)
2.Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat (v1.19.0)

On my machine I have installed JDK 18.0.1.1 and Apache Maven 3.9.0

Issue is when I run mvn --version command from Integrated Terminal in VS Code it gives me following error
"Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse --add-exports /: /com.sun.tools.javac.processing"

I am able to run mvn --version successfully on Windows Terminal independently, only the integrated Terminal in VS Code has issue.

Can someone help by providing any direction about this issue. I am new to VS Code and completely clueless of the error.

Open integrated Terminal in VS Code and try mvn --version command. It should print the version for maven.